# Hibernate related object not hydrated

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception

Please see code below. DeviceDAO, Device, and Mobileuser are hibernate generated objects. the process works until i get to the second "if" conditional where I call mobileUser.getPin(). The problem is that mobileUser's properties (such as pin) are null. The values exist in the DB, but they area null, so my calls throw null pointer exceptions. Mobileuser's properties haven't been hydrated by hibernate. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
DeviceDAO deviceDao = new DeviceDAO();
    List<Device> devices = deviceDao.findByUdid(requestTokenModel.getUdid());

                if(!devices.isEmpty())
            {
                Device device = devices.get(0);
                Mobileuser mobileUser =device.getMobileuser();
                if(mobileUser.getPin().contentEquals(requestTokenModel.getPiin()) && mobileUser.getIsactive() == "Y")
                        {
                            //omitted                       
                        }
            }
```

**UPDATE**

Here's some more information as requested:

I am using MyEclipse Hibernate Reverse Engineering to generated data objects and DAO objects. Using annotations for mapping.

Here is Mobileuser.java

```
     package com.myeclipse.hibernate;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

/**
 * Mobileuser entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "MOBILEUSER", schema = "WARPVALID")
public class Mobileuser implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private Integer mobileuserid;
    private Servicetype servicetype;
    private String lastname;
    private String username;
    private String firstname;
    private String organization;
    private String piin;
    private String isactive;
    private Date createdate;
    private Date modifydate;
    private String email;
    private String isaccepted;
    private Set<Registration> registrations = new HashSet<Registration>(0);
    private Set<Device> devices = new HashSet<Device>(0);

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public Mobileuser() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public Mobileuser(String lastname, String username, String firstname,
            String piin, String isactive, Date createdate, Date modifydate,
            String isaccepted) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.username = username;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.piin = piin;
        this.isactive = isactive;
        this.createdate = createdate;
        this.modifydate = modifydate;
        this.isaccepted = isaccepted;
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public Mobileuser(Servicetype servicetype, String lastname,
            String username, String firstname, String organization,
            String piin, String isactive, Date createdate, Date modifydate,
            String email, String isaccepted, Set<Registration> registrations,
            Set<Device> devices) {
        this.servicetype = servicetype;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.username = username;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.organization = organization;
        this.piin = piin;
        this.isactive = isactive;
        this.createdate = createdate;
        this.modifydate = modifydate;
        this.email = email;
        this.isaccepted = isaccepted;
        this.registrations = registrations;
        this.devices = devices;
    }

    // Property accessors
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "MOBILEUSERID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 9, scale = 0)
    public Integer getMobileuserid() {
        return this.mobileuserid;
    }

    public void setMobileuserid(Integer mobileuserid) {
        this.mobileuserid = mobileuserid;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SERVICETYPEID")
    public Servicetype getServicetype() {
        return this.servicetype;
    }

    public void setServicetype(Servicetype servicetype) {
        this.servicetype = servicetype;
    }

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Column(name = "ORGANIZATION", length = 50)
    public String getOrganization() {
        return this.organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(String organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    @Column(name = "PIIN", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getPiin() {
        return this.piin;
    }

    public void setPiin(String piin) {
        this.piin = piin;
    }

    @Column(name = "ISACTIVE", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public String getIsactive() {
        return this.isactive;
    }

    public void setIsactive(String isactive) {
        this.isactive = isactive;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "CREATEDATE", nullable = false, length = 7)
    public Date getCreatedate() {
        return this.createdate;
    }

    public void setCreatedate(Date createdate) {
        this.createdate = createdate;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "MODIFYDATE", nullable = false, length = 7)
    public Date getModifydate() {
        return this.modifydate;
    }

    public void setModifydate(Date modifydate) {
        this.modifydate = modifydate;
    }

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", length = 50)
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "ISACCEPTED", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public String getIsaccepted() {
        return this.isaccepted;
    }

    public void setIsaccepted(String isaccepted) {
        this.isaccepted = isaccepted;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mobileuser")
    public Set<Registration> getRegistrations() {
        return this.registrations;
    }

    public void setRegistrations(Set<Registration> registrations) {
        this.registrations = registrations;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mobileuser")
    public Set<Device> getDevices() {
        return this.devices;
    }

    public void setDevices(Set<Device> devices) {
        this.devices = devices;
    }

}
```

And this is Device.java:

```
package com.myeclipse.hibernate;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

/**
 * Device entity. @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEVICE", schema = "WARPVALID")
public class Device implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private Integer deviceid;
    private Mobileuser mobileuser;
    private String udid;
    private String applicationversion;
    private String dataversion;
    private Set<Authentication> authentications = new HashSet<Authentication>(0);

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public Device() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public Device(Mobileuser mobileuser, String udid) {
        this.mobileuser = mobileuser;
        this.udid = udid;
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public Device(Mobileuser mobileuser, String udid,
            String applicationversion, String dataversion,
            Set<Authentication> authentications) {
        this.mobileuser = mobileuser;
        this.udid = udid;
        this.applicationversion = applicationversion;
        this.dataversion = dataversion;
        this.authentications = authentications;
    }

    // Property accessors
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "DEVICEID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 9, scale = 0)
    public Integer getDeviceid() {
        return this.deviceid;
    }

    public void setDeviceid(Integer deviceid) {
        this.deviceid = deviceid;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MOBILEUSERID", nullable = false)
    public Mobileuser getMobileuser() {
        return this.mobileuser;
    }

    public void setMobileuser(Mobileuser mobileuser) {
        this.mobileuser = mobileuser;
    }

    @Column(name = "UDID", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getUdid() {
        return this.udid;
    }

    public void setUdid(String udid) {
        this.udid = udid;
    }

    @Column(name = "APPLICATIONVERSION", length = 20)
    public String getApplicationversion() {
        return this.applicationversion;
    }

    public void setApplicationversion(String applicationversion) {
        this.applicationversion = applicationversion;
    }

    @Column(name = "DATAVERSION", length = 20)
    public String getDataversion() {
        return this.dataversion;
    }

    public void setDataversion(String dataversion) {
        this.dataversion = dataversion;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "device")
    public Set<Authentication> getAuthentications() {
        return this.authentications;
    }

    public void setAuthentications(Set<Authentication> authentications) {
        this.authentications = authentications;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your mapping for `Mobileuser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scares me when this happens, but I just got back from lunch and now it's working correctly. Didn't make any changes from before, but it's happy now. No idea what was causing it.

Thanks for the debugging help @Corey.

Comment: This is accepted answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Mobileuser.hbm has a property named "piin" while your Mobileuser class has a method getPin(). Is it possible that one of these is a typo? They should match, assuming that they are meant to represent the same information. As should the setter, setPin(String) or setPiin(String) whichever it should be.

If the db has a column "piin", you can change the mapping to map property pin to column piin, though this means you won't be able to regenerate the mapping from the db in the future.

Comment: Actually the mapping is correct. Initially I changed the code in this message to say PIN as to not confused (guess that backfired). In my actual code, the mapping and teh getter/setter names are corerct(piin, getPiin, setPiin). Thanks.

Comment: So your mapping and file both use piin, and you are still having the problem mentioned...could you add code for Mobileuser.java to the question?

Comment: Mobileuser.java is a very simple serializable POJO object with getters and setters to each persistent property.

Comment: I switched to annotated mode (updated question above) and am still seeing this issue. Feel like I'm losing my mind on this one! Any ideas?

Comment: You could tell hibernate to show the sql it is running, via the property hibernate.show_sql. Then you could at least make sure that it is selecting the PIIN column.

Comment: Some other info that may be useful doing "remote asynchronous" debugging - what hibernate version are you using? How are you managing the hibernate session (ie, what opens and closes the session and how does DeviceDao know what session to use)?

Comment: There's also a generated session factory that checks if there is a current session and uses it, otherwise it creates one.

Comment: The issue could be some kind of lazy loading - I thought it would throw a LazyInitializationException if so, but it sounds like you may not have a that hibernate session anymore by the time you call mobileUser.getPin(). You could test this out by changing the annotation on Device.getMobileUser to use FetchType.EAGER. If this solves your problem, you can either take the possibly sizable performance hit when you load a device but don't use the mobileuser or you can look at ways to ensure the same session is available and open when you make the dao call and when you call getPin.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried changing the fetch type to EAGER for that property. No dice. I even tried wrapping the entire call in a transaction to preserve the session.

Comment: I don't think I can help much more via Q&A...would need to look at your code in the debugger, I think.

Comment: +1 for the help. I'll try to get the db debugger up and running.